# Implement a navigation controller into a tabbar controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Okay I have a well known problem. I want to implement a tableview controller into a navigation controller. And this navigation controller should be implemented in a tabbar controller.

I am using XCode 4.2 and I started a new project with a tabbar controller template
Now what I did was in the xib file from firstViewController deleted the view and added a navigation controller with a tableview controller in it.

I connected the files owner view to the tableview item. But when I build and run it only shows the table view and not the navigation controller.

Can anybody help?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the TabBarController Application. In this application you will see how to implement NavigationController and TableView together in the TabBarController application:

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/tabbarcontroller-with-navigationcontroller-and-tableview-in-iphone/